# Why does MapReduce bother mapping every value to 1 in the map step?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to figure out MapReduce and so far I think I'm gaining an okay understanding.

However, one thing confuses me.  In every example and explanation of MapReduce I can find, the map step maps all values to 1.  For instance, in the most common example (counting occurrences of words in a string), the Map section splits up each word and then maps it to the value 1.

The Reduce section then combines/reduces like words, adding up the amount of times they occur so that they map to N instead of 1 (N being how many times the word appears).

What I don't understand is: why even bother mapping them to 1 in the first place?  It seems like they will ALWAYS map to 1.  Why not just split them apart, and then in the Reduce step, do the mapping there, and sum everything up at the same time?

I'm sure there must be a good reason that I just can't think of.  Thanks!

(this question is about MapReduce as a concept in general, not necessarily about Hadoop or any other specific technology or implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the mapper is decided based on the use case you wanted to have. In word count, we want the mapper to separate the individual words and output the number of occurrences for each word. The mapper is called for every key value pair(input split) in the input. Here its for each line. Key is the offset and value is the entire sentence. There would be grouping performed before the reducer is invoked. so all the words are grouped and each occurence(1 here) is counted. It is not a hard rule to emit 1 as mapper output. If you have noticed the data set example in Hadoop : Definitive guide, they have the year and temperature emitted as mapper output. The usecase is to group based on the years and find the max/min temperature. You can think of this as group parameter, for a basic understanding sake. Happy learning